# You should mind your P's first

Tags: word, wordplay, lateral-thinking, language

This should be short and sweet.

> Given his strength, he must be the almighty. Given his health, he must use ointments. Given his status, should we board his ark?

Hint 1:

> This puzzle has been intentionally altered.

Hint 2:

> I love red herrings, how about you? Given his mind, he must *too*.

Hint 3:

> An [afix-riddle](/questions/tagged/afix-riddle), without a clue; perhaps, just maybe, the prefix will do?

Hint 4:

> It's not quite the same, but it's not different either.

Hint 5:

> [homonym](/questions/tagged/homonym)s are my favorite nymonyms.

Hint 6:

> The first is *palm*, but why?

---

What are the three P's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I see the intended solution, but not sure if I'm missing something. I believe the 3 Ps are:

> palm, point, park

Which we arrive at by:

> Prefixing a 'P' before 'almighty', 'ointments' and 'ark', respectively.

I guess

> A palm can signify strength? (Though a clenched fist probably more-so.)
>  But not sure how 'point' or 'park' relate to their clues.
>  I recognize that with the reference "should we board his ark?", there may be allusion to Noah's Ark, (plus the first clue mentions "the almighty"), but not sure where the second clue fits in with this.

And regarding the hints,

> Hint 1:
> This puzzle has been intentionally altered.

> I guess this is referencing that the puzzle's title was originally "You should mind your P's **last**" but was quickly edited to its current version? But not sure why that's a hint if the old version of the title is irrelevant.

> Hint 2:
> I love red herrings, how about you? Given his mind, he must *too*

> Another reference to Noah?

The rest of the hints are

> more straightforward I believe, hinting at the category of puzzle to think about, and eventually outright telling us the first part of the solution.

Comment: By clarifying some points, hopefully it'll make sense; rot13(gur gvgyr punatr cbvagf lbh gb gur raq bs rnpu cnffntr; gur cbvag bs rnpu cnffntr vf gb qverpg lbhe nggragvba njnl sebz gur raq bs gur yvar, ubjrire gurl vagragvbanyyl qba'g znxr frafr gb uryc erqverpg lbhe nggragvba gb gur raq bs gur yvar; uvag gjb vgnyvpvmrf gur jbeq gbb, fvzcyl orpnhfr vg'f ng gur raq bs gur yvar; uvag guerr vf qverpgvat lbh gb hgvyvmr whfg gur cersvk bs gur jbeqf).

Comment: I saw this a while ago but it still does not make sense to me. What am I missing? Why  these three and not say pal, point, and par? Or phis, pa, or pal, which I was also considering as possibilities.  It seems there must be some sort of logical tie in or connector between these words that acts as validation and proves a unique answer, but I am still stumped.

Comment: @Amoz there isn't a logical tie in; it involves lateral thinking focused on the fact that the phrases do not make any sense together, particularly the last word of each sentence is the major deviation; what do each of these things have to do with each other? The words chosen were picked at random from a list of known rot13(ubzbalzf); the phrases themselves describe nothing and are simply there as red herrings (hence why they make *some* sense when reading them).

Comment: The primary focus of the puzzle is to figure out which words were the focus of the wordplay tag, then, work your way to the answer utilizing common tactics.

Comment: But if the words are random, how are solvers supposed to know that they have the correct answer? The whole paragraph after "I guess" in this answer shows how the poster tries to find conformation, but can't make head or tails of the answer. I think the puzzle would be better if each of the sentences described its P-word somehow. For what it's worth, I find the hints very unhelpful.

Comment: Anyway, well done on solving this, but given the title, I feel the puzzle [missed](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/qualm) [a big](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quoin) [opportunity](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quark).

Comment: @MOehm this puzzle was meant to be difficult, but in it's original state, it *is* solvable (I had a friend and coworker solve it first). Solving it *requires* [tag:lateral-thinking] to a high degree. The initial title stating "last" and the edit to "first" was to help emphasize that *last* was important to the solution. It's not the first time an edit was a part of the puzzle. It just so happens an interim edit was made (good Samaritans unite) which *sort of* distracted from this point (hence the hint saying it was intentional).

Comment: I don't want to distract from your point though; I concur that I could have made this better by making it a bit easier to solve. I'll take that into consideration while I make future puzzles.

Comment: @Amoz Good point regarding other potential solutions using the same technique. Somehow missed them haha (though the first answer was already given in the hints, which I did read before solving)